# FATAL ERROR: Received unexpected end-of-file from SFTP server

Tags: ssh, permissions, sftp, nginx

i have a sftp connection and it is working fine, this was the previous working setup:

```
#ADDED starts
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match group sftpgroup
ChrootDirectory %h
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp -d /upload
#ADDED ends
```

now instead of `home/upload`, I am trying to set the root directory to the laravel storage folder directly and updated it to:

```
#ADDED starts
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match group sftpgroup
ChrootDirectory %h
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp -d ~/project.com/storage/app/public/upload
#ADDED ends
```

the group and permission of the upload folder:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 forge www-data 4096 Sep 20 13:41 upload
```

and the group of `sftpuser`

```
sftpuser : sftpgroup www-data
```

Error I am receiving after the update: `FATAL ERROR: Received unexpected end-of-file from SFTP server`

Permissions of all parent folder of `upload`:

```
forge@abc:~/project.com/storage/app$ ls -ld ~/{,project.com/{,storage/{,app/{,public/{,upload}}}}}
drwxr-xr-x+  9 forge forge    4096 Sep 20 13:14 /home/forge/
drwxrwxr-x  16 forge forge    4096 Sep 20 13:30 /home/forge/project.com/
drwxrwxr-x   5 forge www-data 4096 Sep 20 13:14 /home/forge/project.com/storage/
drwxrwxr-x   4 forge www-data 4096 Sep 20 13:41 /home/forge/project.com/storage/app/
drwxrwxr-x   3 forge www-data 4096 Sep 26 01:48 /home/forge/project.com/storage/app/public/
drwxrwxr-x   2 forge www-data 4096 Sep 26 01:48 /home/forge/project.com/storage/app/public/upload
```

Comment: Try instead of `~/` to specify the full path.

Comment: Does `sftpuser` or `sftpgroup` have x permissions on all parent directories of ~/project.com/storage/app/upload ? To phrase this differently: can you show us the output from `ls -ld ~/{,project.com/{,storage/{,upload}}}`?

Comment: @Lucas I have updated my question please look

Comment: @harrymc I have also tried by replacing `~/` to `/home/forge/project.com/storage/app/public/upload`, now its logging int to sftp, however, instead of taking me to upload directory it is listing files from `/` directory

Comment: It might be a matter of permissions, if not of the folder itself, then of some intermediate folder in the hierarchy.

Comment: @harrymc I have added the permissions list of all folder in above questions. Could you please check it and let me know.

Comment: See the two answers in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244406/how-do-i-give-www-data-user-to-a-folder-in-my-home-folder). If one works for you, I'll add it here.